# iPhone QRCode encoding library

Tags: iphone

I need to create QRCode in my app  and I used  [OBJQREncoder](https://github.com/jverkoey/ObjQREncoder). I tried with the **QRUI** example within this, and it can encode about 0-20 characters.

When I increase the character count QRCode is disappeared from the screen(Blank Screen). I need to use this library in my app and need to encode about 40-50 chars. How can I over come this blank screen?

Answer (score 1):

Try out this. This will increase the character count to 100 +
[QREncoder encode:@"http://www.google.com/" size:6 correctionLevel:QRCorrectionLevelLow];